# Creating global 'for' variable. Should be 'for (var items ...'

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I am using jshint. Can anyone tell me why it's treating "for" keyword as global variable?

> Creating global 'for' variable. Should be 'for (var items ...'

Here's the loop:

```
//items and properties are defined above...
var items = null, properties = someObject;

//code here is properly terminated with ; "semicolon"

for (items in properties) {
    if (properties.hasOwnProperty(items)) {
        //some code here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of JSHint are you using? I can't get it to raise that warning with your code.

Comment: jshint.com doesn't give that result, so the issue is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Are you sure `var items = null` occurs in the same scope as `for (items in properties) {}`?

Comment: Yes the items is declared within the same scope. Also the same js file is passed successfully with "jslint". But "jshint" is giving this error. Actually we are migrating from jslint to jshint that's why mentioned about it.

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer as well documented everywhere..

```
for (items in properties) { }
```

should be:

```
for (var items in properties) { }
```

*(i know this is necroposting)*

Answer (score 4):

It is nothing to do with `for` but with `items` *within* the for construct.

If you go like

```
for (items in properties) {
```

and `items` were not previously defined, then `items` would be a global variable. Since JSHint is complaining, you probably don't declare `items` it in the scope of the for construct, even though you let it look like that in your example code.

If it's really defined, then I would suggest file a bug report with JSHint :-)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is "*why* is JSHint raising the warning when it shouldn't be?".

Comment: So this is basically a large comment? :)

Comment: What I meant to say is that he should check if items is *really* defined. Updated.

Comment: This is not possible because items is declared within the same scope. Also the same js file is passed successfully with "jslint". But "jshint" is giving this error. Actually we are migrating from jslint to jshint that's why mentioned about it.

Comment: Okay, weird. Then I would assume it's a bug in JSHint. Congrats on finding one :-) Do you use the latest version?

Comment: Yup I am using jshint v2.0.1 which is latest :)

Comment: Then I can't think of anything else than that it's a bug in JSHint!

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a bug in JSHint: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1016

Comment: Should be fixed in 2.5.7 (coming soon): https://github.com/jshint/jshint/commit/b55b3e1b0ec2425d5aedf9e67b3a28c0290e2b65 .